# After Rails 3 upgrade rake db:test:prepare not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake, rspec2

I have just gone through the process of upgrading a Rails 2.3.11 app that uses Test Unit to Rails 3.1.rc4 and I have now set up rspec-rails 2.6.1.

I also switch the test connection in `database.yml` to use sqlite instead of postgres.

I can run `rake db:migrate` and `db:test:prepare` all day, but in my model tests I get "Could not find table 'model_name'".

Has anyone else ran into this?

Comment: try bundle exec rake db:setup ?

Comment: @CountCet: I got the same problem here, but when running `guard`. `bundle install`, `rake db:reset` and `rake db:test:prepare` fixed it here, but I still don't know why it happened in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I did encounter this before. Try rebuilding it from scratch:

```
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Answer (score 0):

What does select * from schema_migrations show you? Verify that the migrations you expect have all actually been stored. If you know which migration failed you can use `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=<VERSION>`

Apologies for not being a comment. StackOverflow's "can't comment until 50" policy seems a bit backwards :)